# Limit Answers on Selection

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible to make the selection with a limit of numbers?

Example, I wish to allows my visitors to register for my event. 
And I only have 50 seats for VIP, as if they select VIP category for 2 pax, I have to remain 48 availability for others.

Anyone can advise me how can I do so?

Answer (score 2):

You can limit selections in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) by assigning [quantity limits](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/quantity-limits) to your choice fields.  Simply do the following:

1. Select **Limit Quantities** under *Choice Options*
2. Enter quantities for each type of seat, or leave blank for unlimited
3. Enter the **Quantity Exceeded Error Message** to something like *No more seats of this type are available!*

You can learn more about quantity limits in our [help documentation](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/18/building-forms/limiting-quantities)!

[image: limit quantities for choice fields in Cognito Forms]

Answer (score 0):

There is an add-on called Form Limiter that will accomplish what you need. See: https://sites.google.com/a/newvisions.org/scripts_resources/add-ons/formlimiter